# How can I render in blender via GPU on my 64 bit PC that has Intel HD graphics 620 as well as radeon 27 m445 display adapters?

Tags: rendering

I read a tutorial on this site about rendering in windows 7. I have installed windows 10 pro, which is similar to 7. You told me to download drivers according to my display adapters but they are not present in NVIDIA site. I am using DELL 5567 model laptop. I want to render via GPU in blender. You can see more details in my question. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

First, the radeon is an AMD graphics card, not an NVidia, so you won't find drivers for it on NVidia's site.

Second, while blender can use openCL, it demands a reasonably modern GPU. Yours seems to be a bit older, so not sure blender will be able to use it, even with the proper drivers. (see [the blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) for more details)